# thesis: a plethora of technical parameters, how to present it concisely?

Tags: thesis, writing

I'm writing my masters thesis at the moment. The topic of my thesis is the evaluation of one classification algorithm. Due to its technical nature I have to give a lot of context for each experimental setup. Something like the choice of signals to be classified for example:

The signals tested in this experiment were fsk signals with the following technical parameters:

Shift/Symbolrate

```
500/75
500/150
500/200
500/250
350/150
350/75 Each of the signals contained 20 header information and 80% payload
```

500/75

Due to the thesis containing about 20 experiments of various sorts, I'm not sure on how to best present my information concisely.

Would you try and make a subsection for each experiment, use a table or present it in plain text?

Comment: Plain text is hard to read.  Twenty subsections could get messy.  Can you find some way of grouping them?  Tables could help you format things in a way that's easier on the eyes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for writing advice, not a question about academia.

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule, if you are presenting a large body of numbers in a structured way (e.g., similar parameters corresponding to a set of experiments) it is best to present them in tabular form.  I would suggest trying to put your parameters into a clear table-format that allows the reader to consult the parameters for each individual experiment easily.  If this is material that must be included for completeness, but is not interesting in its own right, you might also consider relegating this table to an appendix, and referring to it in the body with an appropriate reference.